# i need help in applying sfFeed2Plugin

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

i installed the plugin and cannot find anything that tells me how it works and how to use it.
i have the icon in place and an empty onClick event

in homeSuccess.php:

```
<input class='submit_img' type="image" src="/images/rainbow/feed-icon-14x14.png" value="Feed" alt="Feed" onClick="gotoFeed(this.value,<?php echo $usr_profile->getId();?>)">
```

gotoFeed JS in homeSuccess.php:

```
function gotoFeed(id)
{

   console.log("testing");      
   //must redirect to  feeds page??
}
```

in the actions class:

```
public function executeFeed(sfWebRequest $request)
{
    $profile_id = $this->getUser()->getAttribute('profile_id','zero');      
}
```

can anybody help please?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the complete tutorial at this link [sfFeed2Plugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfFeed2Plugin), just clicking the tab [Readme](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfFeed2Plugin/1_2_5?tab=plugin_readme)

**UPDATE**

I'm using this plugin with an action like this in my action class:

```
  public function executeFeedRss(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $feed = new sfRss201Feed();

    $feed->setTitle('MySite');
    $feed->setLink($this->generateUrl('@homepage'));

    $c = new Criteria;
    $c->addDescendingOrderByColumn(PostPeer::CREATED_AT);
    $c->setLimit(10);
    $Posts = PostPeer::doSelect($c);

    foreach ($Posts as $post)
    {
      $item = new sfFeedItem();
      $item->setTitle($post->getTitle());

      // according to routing rule
      $item->setLink($this->generateUrl('@posts', array('id'=>$post->getId())));

      $item->setPubdate($post->getCreatedAt('U'));
      $item->setUniqueId($post->getSlug());
      $item->setDescription($post->getBody());

      $feed->addItem($item);
    }    
    $this->feed = $feed;
  }
```

and this code inside the template `feedRssSuccess.php`:

```
<?php decorate_with(false) ?>
<?php echo $feed->asXml(ESC_RAW) ?>
```

Finally simply I have a link to this action in my layout through a template, but of course in a pageSuccess.php is the same.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: thank you i have the plugin and am going through the readme but i have an existing app with a self written rainbowcodePlugin and want to incorporate the feed plugin using my existing tables...the feed plugin is built around 2 other tables. how can i make the feed plugin work for me? thanks

Comment: I posted my snippet... thinking out laud... if your the feed plugin is built around 2 other tables, why you can't build a criteria/query and replace `$c = new Criteria;
    $c->addDescendingOrderByColumn(PostPeer::CREATED_AT);
    $c->setLimit(10);
    $Posts = PostPeer::doSelect($c);` also replace the routing rule and so work with this code... maybe I misunderstood your question.

Comment: yikes im so confused dont know whether im coming or going :) i'll start from scratch. i want to incorporate an rss feed on my website. i ran the command: ./symfony plugin:install sfFeed2Plugin-1.2.5.tgz and unpacked it. in my plugins directory i now have the sfFeed2Plugin directory with the license,readme and lib entries. i am following the readme but i need the plugin to work with my existing tables. all entries in the lib directory are using other tables. how do i go about making this plugin to work for me? all modules of my website are also contained in a plugin called rainbowcodePlugin.

Comment: Do you use `Propel` or `Doctrine`?

Comment: propel... i was thinking, maybe i should follow the Practical Symfony Day 14: Feeds(much simpler), and make use of the jobeet database because i have that. only thing now is how to configure my code to access the jobeet database as well so for the feeds part read the jobs table?